# Why are some of my flags are aged away while some older ones are still pending?

Tags: bug, flags, flag-history

Example:

[image: Screenshot of aged away flag]

[image: Screenshot of pending flag]

Comment: I can't see the screenshot so I can't tell if it applies, but I believe flags are aged away after about 14 days. I know there's an MSE post about the aging mechanic, I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: The pending flag was submitted on 12 Mar 2011, the aged away one on 11 Feb 2015.

Comment: Then it might be that it's a type of flag that does not age away. (I don't think every flag type ages, I know flags for closure do)

Comment: "not a real question" is not currently a valid flag. I guess that one's fallen through a gap and will be there forever, subject to a developer giving it a snip.

Comment: [This answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204347/266735) on MSE covers all current scenarios for flags or close votes aging away.